# different audio on different devices

Tags: bluetooth, audio, music

I am going on a trip with my son and want my music to play through bluetooth and his youtube to play through the phones speakers, is this possible

Comment: So the phone would have a music app in the background streaming over bluetooth, and your son watching videos via YouTube in the foreground?  Very interesting setup, wonder if there is a solution.

Comment: I'm trying to play games on my phone, and have the game audio play on my phone while music is playing through my bluetooth speaker, and I can't find a way to do that.